# Weka decision tree prediction NA treatment on missing values

Tags: tree, weka, decision-tree, missing-data

Hi at the moment I'm working on implementing a big Hellinger distance decision tree and I have encountered a problem. I have a continuous variable in the tree node and I don't know how the tree will predict if I will have a missing value for that variable.
For example that node has splitting criterion <250 and >=250. What path the tree will chose when predicting?
The tree training data had also missing values in that variable.

Maybe I should replace all missing values with a specific number?

Answer (score 0):

You may take your action depending on the behavior of the variable. Also consider the impact of the value for the classifier. So if it can be generalized the you may use min/max/mean values for your missing values.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to insist that the input does not contain Nulls, then the user can find a way to encode it before fitting. If you make a choice then you are forcing future users to use your choice.